# How can I get the channels added to my custom app in MS teams?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

I have created a custom app from app studio in MS teams and added to some of the channel,
Now I want the list of channel in which custom app is added using Microsoft Graph API java sdk.

Thank You !!

Answer (score 0):

There is no API to get channels where your app has been added.

Probably, you need to list all teams and inside each team list all channels and inside each channel filter tab belonging to your app.

```
IGraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient.builder().authenticationProvider( authProvider ).buildClient();

// get teams
ITeamCollectionPage teams = graphClient.teams()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();

// iterate over each team to get channels
IChannelCollectionPage channels = graphClient.teams("{teamId}").channels()
    .buildRequest()
    .get();

// iterate over each channel and filter tab
ITeamsTabCollectionPage tabs = graphClient.teams("{teamId}").channels("{channelId}").tabs()
.buildRequest()
.filter("teamsApp/id eq 'your_app_id'")
.expand("teamsApp")
.get();
```

Comment: here 'your_app_id' is the app name or the Id which we get when we click on generate button while creating a app in App studio?

Comment: It's the name of the package I guess as value of "your_app_id", I tried with both package name and code generated while creating a app but it's giving me empty list of tabs in json data.

Comment: Is there another way? from app only I can fetch the list of channel where it is added?

Comment: 'Your App id' Refer to  the app ID when you upload it to app Catalog. To use the App you need to upload the application to app catalog. Please check this [API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/teamsapp-publish?view=graph-rest-1.0) to publish to APP catalog. You will receive the APP id in the response and use that id to fetch the list of channels.

Comment: @user2250152 Is there a way so I can get only the list where my app is added I don't want to iterate a every channel to find a tab. Is my app will have such data where i can see all the channels?

Comment: Currently we don't have any API to get the list where the app got installed. Could you please raise a [user Voice](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public-preview/category/182881-developer-platform)?